# Format string with multiple parameters so that MySQL can proces them

Tags: python, mysql, string, where-in

I want to know how I can format a string that is returned by the API so that Mysql can process it.

This is the string my API returns: `bad_string = "History,Romance,Business & Money"`

Attempt 1:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE scrape_category IN (%s) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15", bad_string)
```

Returns this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PATH", line 23, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE scrape_category IN (%s) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15", bad_string)
  File "C:\PATH\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 259, in execute
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Attempt 2:

```
bad_string_2 = "'Romance', 'History', 'Business & Money'"

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE scrape_category IN (%s) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15", bad_string_2)
```

Returns this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:PATH", line 21, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE scrape_category IN (%s) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15", bad_string_2)
  File "C:\PATH\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 246, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "C:\PATH\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 520, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

This works:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE scrape_category IN ('Romance', 'History', 'Business & Money') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15")
```

---

The query works when i do this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE scrape_category IN ('Romance', 'History', 'Business & Money') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15")
```

**How do I format the string and make MySQL return results?**

Comment: I should have been more explicit: you need to *split apart your `bad_string` into separate values*. Preferably you do this in your form, before sending it to your Flask view. Take a look at the [`MultiDict.getlist()` method](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist), if you use the same parameter name more than once, you can get a list, e.g. calling your view with `/preferred_categories?categories=Romance&categories=History&categories&Business%20%26%20Money` then using `categories = request.args.getlist('categories')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with some like this :

```
filter ="History,Romance,Business & Money".split(',')
sqlcommand = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE scrape_category IN ({0})".format(
    ', '.join(['%s'] * len(filter)))
print(sqlcommand)
cursor.execute(sqlcommand, filter)
```

Comment: This works excellent! Thank you very much! You made my day :D

Answer (score 0):

Your string value is:
     `"History,Romance,Business & Money"`

and you need this: `'Romance', 'History', 'Business & Money'`

try something like `bad_string = " 'Romance', 'History', 'Business & Money' "`

Hope it helps...